# Helm and minikube: service ip missing

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am trying examples from the book *Learning Helm*. I seem to be missing something. I cannot install chart from helm repo:

```
xxxxx:~ $ helm install my-nginx bitnami/nginx
NAME: my-nginx
LAST DEPLOYED: Sat Jan  9 20:26:22 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
** Please be patient while the chart is being deployed **

NGINX can be accessed through the following DNS name from within your cluster:

    my-nginx.default.svc.cluster.local (port 80)

To access NGINX from outside the cluster, follow the steps below:

1. Get the NGINX URL by running these commands:

  NOTE: It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
        Watch the status with: 'kubectl get svc --namespace default -w my-nginx'

    export SERVICE_PORT=$(kubectl get --namespace default -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].port}" services my-nginx)
    export SERVICE_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace default my-nginx -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
    echo "http://${SERVICE_IP}:${SERVICE_PORT}"
```

```
xxxxx:~ $ export SERVICE_PORT=$(kubectl get --namespace default -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].port}" services my-nginx)
xxxxx:~ $ export SERVICE_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace default my-nginx -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
xxxxx:~ $ echo "http://${SERVICE_IP}:${SERVICE_PORT}"
http://:80
```

```
$ kubectl get svc --namespace default -w my-nginx
NAME       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
my-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.104.16.177   <pending>     80:30977/TCP  17h
```

Some more details.

Comment: I am using my Ubuntu laptop. (That was removed form title header  by JK). Dont know if that has any relevance here?

Comment: Are you using the local Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Yes: I have Minikube default installation on my Ubuntu laptop. Just came to think if this bitnami/nginx just does not have this external IP (pre-) configured. I am new to helm + kubernetes, just started learn about them. With that new Helm book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line in the following to extract the service IP is to get the external IP in the service object.

```
export SERVICE_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace default my-nginx -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
```

In `LoadBalancer` service type, Kubernetes tries to get an external IP address and release the target service with that IP address. In self-hosted Kubernetes cluster, the external IP cannot be provisioned automatically. In most of the hosted clusters in public cloud, like GKE, EKS etc, they have had the integration with the external IP address provision. So, you can get it automatically once you set up the service as `LoadBalancer`.

It is still possible to do this automation with 3rd party operators/applications, like [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/). But in most of the self-hosted Kubernetes cluster, it is suggested to access the service with `NodePort` service type.

Please rerun the helm command with the follow argument. It will change the service type from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort`. Following the instruction from the stdout may allow you to access your service.

```
> helm install my-nginx bitnami/nginx --set service.type=NodePort
```

On the other hand, you can follow the minikube official doc [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#run-tunnel-in-a-separate-terminal) to set up the support in `LoadBalancer` service.